# method in protocol extension gets called instead of method implementation in View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols, protocol-extension

so I have a viewController which holds a custom view,

and that viewController class conforms to `ViewProtocol`

I expect when `someAction` method triggered in `someCustomizedView`

it will print `" method in otherCustomizedClass called "`

but it prints `(" method in extension Called")` instead.

The `theNotOptionalMethod` works just fine but not the optional method.

Is there anything that I misunderstand of protocol extension ?

Please help, been struggling for hours, thanks

```
protocol ViewDelegate: class {

    func theNOTOptionalMethod()

}

extension ViewDelegate {

    func theOptionalMethod(){
        print (" method in extension Called")
    }
}

class someCustomizedView: UIView {

    weak var deleage: ViewDelegate?

    @IBAction func someAction(sender: UIButton) {
        deleage?.theOptionalMethod()
    }
}

class someCustomizedVC: UIViewController, ViewDelegate {

    lazy var someView: someCustomizedView = {
        var v = someCustomizedView()
        v.deleage = self
        return v
    }()


    //...... someView added to controller


    func theNOTOptionalMethod() {
        // do nothing
    }

    func theOptionalMethod() {
        print (" method in otherCustomizedClass called ")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how methods in extensions work. They hide the implementations in a class.

To create a protocol with optional methods, you need to put the optional method in the protocol definition:

```
protocol ViewDelegate: class {

    func theNOTOptionalMethod()
    func theOptionalMethod()

}
```

Alternatively, you can use `@objc` and `optional` modifiers:

```
@objc protocol MyDelegate : class{
    func notOptionalMethod()
    @objc optional func optionalMethod()
}
```

When you call `optionalMethod`, you need to unwrap the optional:

```
delegate.optionalMethod?()
```

Comment: I've been reading these swift hacks https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-make-optional-protocol-methods
that I thought they are the same...so there're not.

Comment: @Ian I just realised that you forgot to put the optional method in the protocol definition itself. You need to do that. See the edit.

Comment: right, I need to go back to read protocol extension documentation again :( thanks for helping